# If Not <variable> Is Nothing Then set value from second row to the last

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem stated in subject

My best is

```
If Not <variable> Is Nothing Then <variable>.EntireColumn.Value = "Customer"
```

so for example

```
If Not C Is Nothing Then C.EntireColumn.Value = "Customer"
```

However it changes entire column, so the first row as well, which is header. My goal is to do that from second row to avoid header change, to the last available, not empty row in this column

Hope anyone can help me on that

I've tried something like

```
CellsToAnonimize = Range(Cells(C.Row, C.Column), Cells(C.Row, C.Column)).End(xlDown)

For Each Cell In CellsToAnonimize
    Cell.Value = "Customer"
    
    Next Cell
```

Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: what is your <variable> type? A Range?

Comment: Yes it is range

The whole code is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738130/if-criteria-doesnt-match-change-value-from-second-to-last-row

Comment: See my answer, you are close with your `CellsToAnon` idea but you don't need to loop through them with `For Each` you can just assign the value in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Range(Cells(2, c.Column).Address, Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row, c.Column).Address).Value2 = "Customer"
```

This can be broken down into more readable code with an example for column "B" like so:

```
Sub e()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim c As Long

Set rng = Range("B1") ' set example for column "B"

If Not c Is Nothing Then
    
    ' get column number into variable `c`
    c = rng.Column
    
    ' get last row into `lRow`
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row

    ' start at row 2 down to lRow for column c
    Range(Cells(2, c).Address, Cells(lRow, c).Address).Value2 = "Customer" 
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Could you please include the code from the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738130/if-criteria-doesnt-match-change-value-from-second-to-last-row

 because obviously I am making something in wrong order and don't know how to fix it?

Comment: Okay I figured it out however it makes only the set rng, it doesnt go through all columns which is not complementary to the macro from the previous link